# casesensitive url’s on linux server

Tags: http

i have moved my html only (not dinamic site) from windows server to linux server now i've problem with casesensitive url's.

for example: i've a file named "Test.htm" and i can't access the file when i type "test.htm" ..

i've tried to modify .htaccess file but failed, i've not enough knowledge for this.

can you recommend me how can i handle this problem,i m looking for better solution then changing all the filenames and url's.

thanks.

Comment: The URLs are not case-sensitive, the underlying file system is.

Comment: @jscott, URLs *are* case-sensitive. Whether the mapping to a file is depends on the underlying file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Apache, try this solution:

Add this line to /etc/apache2/mods-available/speling.load:

```
CheckSpelling on
```

Enable speling module by this command:

```
a2enmod speling
```

And restart Apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Otherwise I strongly recommend to have strict name convention of files that matches with their URL.

Comment: If you want mod_spelling to just fix the case of the URLs you should use the following directive too: `CheckCaseOnly On`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [mod_speling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html) for a solution for this problem in your web server or use something like [ciopfs](http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/) to solve the problem on the file system level (without renaming the files, which would be the best solution).

I'd go with `mod_speling` and progrssively fix the filenames and their links in your web pages.